# how to predict a character based on character based RNN model?

Tags: nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

i want to create a prediction function  which complete a part of "sentence"
the model used here is  a character based RNN(LSTM). what are the steps we should fellow ?
i tried this but i can't give as input the sentence

```
 def generate(self) -> Tuple[List[Token], torch.tensor]:

    start_symbol_idx = self.vocab.get_token_index(START_SYMBOL, 'tokens')
   # print(start_symbol_idx)
    end_symbol_idx = self.vocab.get_token_index(END_SYMBOL, 'tokens')
    padding_symbol_idx = self.vocab.get_token_index(DEFAULT_PADDING_TOKEN, 'tokens')

    log_likelihood = 0.
    words = []
    state = (torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_size), torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_size))

    word_idx = start_symbol_idx

    for i in range(self.max_len):
        tokens = torch.tensor([[word_idx]])

        embeddings = self.embedder({'tokens': tokens})
        output, state = self.rnn._module(embeddings, state)
        output = self.hidden2out(output)

        log_prob = torch.log_softmax(output[0, 0], dim=0)

        dist = torch.exp(log_prob)

        word_idx = start_symbol_idx

        while word_idx in {start_symbol_idx, padding_symbol_idx}:
            word_idx = torch.multinomial(
                dist, num_samples=1, replacement=False).item()

        log_likelihood += log_prob[word_idx]

        if word_idx == end_symbol_idx:
            break

        token = Token(text=self.vocab.get_token_from_index(word_idx, 'tokens'))
        words.append(token)

    return words, log_likelihood,start_symbol_idx
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you find any resources on the web tackling this issue ?

Comment: this code could be helpful for me ?

Comment: What is your goal ? Do you have a trained model that you want to generate from ? Do you want to train a model to generate characters  ? Are you searching for tutorials ? Do you want pointers on how to train /use a machine learning model ?

Comment: i have already a generate function, the code is above, it does not based on an input given by a user to complete a sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two tutorial on how to use machine learning libraries to generate text [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) and [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_generation_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet is the part of allennlp "language model" tutorial, here the generate function is defined to compute the probability of tokens and find the best token and sequence of tokens according to the maximum likelihood of model output, the full code is in the colab notebook bellow you can refer to it: https://colab.research.google.com/github/mhagiwara/realworldnlp/blob/master/examples/generation/lm.ipynb#scrollTo=8AU8pwOWgKxE
after training the the language model for using this function you can say:

```
for _ in range(50):
  tokens, _ = model.generate()
  print(''.join(token.text for token in tokens))
```